# Google Play Services - Map (Incomplete) in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to add `Google Play Services` in my application in the `Xamarin.Android` platform as follows. However, it seems there is something wrong!

Here are the steps that I followed:

**Step 1 : In the components -> Install Google Play Services - Maps**

[image]

**Step 2: Once the installation is completed, it shows as follows**

[image]

When I click on the component, it shows as follows:

[image]

**Step 3: After I get the above error, then I added `GooglePlayServices.Maps.dll` in the References, but still the incomplete message exist.**

[image]

Comment: What Android API level is your app referencing?

Comment: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />`

Comment: Try installing it from Nuget instead of component... `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps` (remove the component first)

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is coming a bit too late but it could help someone.
The solution is really simple. Just use 29.0.0.2 version of Google Play Services - Maps (not the latest one).

Hope this helps.